# Ping on shell scripts: Some packet loss, but error code $? equals to zero. How can I detect?

Tags: shell, ping, packet-loss

Sometimes my DSL router fails in this strange manner:

```
luis@balanceador:~$ sudo ping 8.8.8.8 -I eth9
[sudo] password for luis:
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.3.100 eth9: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=69.3 ms
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=47 time=68.0 ms
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=47 time=68.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=47 time=67.2 ms
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=8 ttl=47 time=67.2 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 5 received, 37% packet loss, time 7012ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 67.254/68.183/69.391/0.906 ms
luis@balanceador:~$ echo $?
0
```

As can be seen, error code `$?` is `0`. So I can not simply detect if the command failed, as the output yields **no error** for any script.

What is the **proper way to detect** that there were some packet loss?
Do I need to **parse** the output with `grep` or there is some simpler method?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ping.8.html) page, by default (on Linux), if ping does not receive any reply packets at all, it will exit with code 1. But if a **packet count** (-c) and deadline timeout (-w, seconds) are both specified, and fewer packets before timeout are received, it will also exit with code 1. On other errors it exits with code 2.

```
ping 8.8.8.8 -I eth9 -c 3 -w 3
```

So, the error code will be set if 3 packets are not received within 3 seconds.

As @mklement0 noted, [ping on BSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ping%288%29) behaves in a bit different way:

> The ping utility exits with one of the following values:
>
> **0**  - at least one response was heard from the specified host.
>
> **2**  - the transmission was successful but no responses were received.

So, in this case one should try workaround it with sending one by one in a loop

```
ip=8.8.8.8
count=3
for i in $(seq ${count}); do
   ping ${ip} -I eth9 -c 1
   if [ $? -eq 2 ]; then
      ## break and retransmit exit code
      exit 2
   fi
done
```

Of course, if you need full statistics, just count codes "2" and "0" to some variables and print result / set error code after *for* loop if you need.

Comment: Good info, but note that it is specific to _GNU_ `ping` (Linux); BSD `ping`, as also used on OS X, has different options and behavior.